# Configuring per-item Windows Updates

Tags: windows-update

There are innumerable reasons why someone would *not* want Windows to automatically apply any and all updates blindly. Most rational people with a modicum of computer knowledge will opt to set Windows to automatically *check* for updates, but let them review the list before manually applying them.

The problem is that there are some updates that we may in fact want automatically applied such as Windows Defender/Security Essentials definitions. Most people will usually want to automatically update those.

The Windows Update configuration dialog seems to only let you turn *everything* on or off.

I don’t suppose that there is any way to configure updates per-item so that some things like malware definitions are automatically updated?

I fear there may be no way to do this for two reasons:

- While the configuration dialog exposes a limited set of options, the registry settings don’t *seem* to offer any more flexibility.
- Allowing this would require some sort of item-specific identifier to distinguish items which seems not to be the case per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/665378/how-can-i-stop-bing-bar-from-showing-up-in-windows-update).

Comment: are you talking about one computer, or many?

Comment: I do believe its one of those even with running your own WSU server it would be one or the other.

Comment: Even with WSUS it's done by category, but you CAN set it to auto-update any new revisions of updates you've previously approved.  more directly to the Defneder updates: there's a WSUS category specifically for signature updates - we had to make a specific WSUS rule to get it to auto approve definitions along with other updated.

Comment: in general: yah, such a feature would be very nice. windows-defender-signature-update: `"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" SignaturesUpdateService -UnmanagedUpdate` (as admin)

Comment: mhh .. you can also tell defender to update it's signatures upon startup via group-policy-editor: "administrative templates" -> "windows components" -> "windows defender"

Comment: `you can also tell defender to update it's signatures upon startup via group-policy-editor` Which might help if you are constantly rebooting, but on a laptop where it is just put to sleep and thus not rebooted for weeks on end, that doesn’t help because Defender/SE doesn’t actually “start”. Also, it doesn’t help with home-premium users. What’s odd and annoying is that there is a setting in MS SE which says to update the defs before scanning, but nothing about updating on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to script updates on command line, on remote computers you can do that with `psexec` - there is a command line tool called `wuinstall` that can do that - gives you complete control over every update you install, you have to be a bit fit at shell scripting though.

If you check the documentation on the website (http://www.wuinstall.com), there are lot of options to select updates - simplest way would be to call

```
wuinstall /install /match "Internet Explorer"
```

to only instal IE updates - you can also filter by product, KB-Numer or regex

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like we will indeed have to rely on third-party tools like this and a few others. I was hoping that Microsoft had enough sense to provide a built-in option, but of course that is just wishful thinking.